# Backup e deploy com shell script

Tags: shell-script

Tenho um ambiente produtivo para o qual realizo a subida de arquivos html, css etc. Porém, toda vez que subo arquivo devo antes fazer um backup das ocorrências já existentes.

Estou tentando construir um script que faça o seguinte:

- Leia o diretório de **upload** e pesquise em produção se aquele arquivo existe, se sim faça um backup
- Copie os arquivos para produção e gere uma lista (txt) dos arquivos copiados
- Caso seja necessário voltar o backup, preciso que o script remova tudo que foi copiado (para remover elementos novos caso existam) e copie de volta os arquivos de backup

Porém, estou bem perdido uma vez em que shell script não é meu forte. Alguém teria alguma ideia de como produzir este script?

Atualmente tenho este trecho de código:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! $1 ]
then
        echo "Informe o nome do diretorio de upload"
        exit 0
fi

DirUpload=/home/upload/$1
DirProducao=/home/producao


cd $DirUpload
find . | sed 's/\.\///g' > upload.txt

for i in `cat $DirUpload/upload.txt`
do
        if [ -d $DirProducao/$i ]
        then
                echo "Diretorio: ${i}"
        elif [ -f $DirProducao/$i ]
        then
                echo "arquivo: ${i}"
        else
                echo "nao encontrado ${DirProducao}/${i}"
        fi
done
```

Por hora estou utilizando o script acima para gerar um txt com a lista a ser carregada, com base nela estou verificando o que atualmente existe em produção para poder copiar para o backup

Comment: O diretório upload já é a produção ?

Comment: upload é o diretório que contêm os arquivos a serem carregados para produção.

Comment: A primeira parte fiz tranquilo, talvez eu termine o restante mais tarde.

Answer (score 2):

Este script vai te ajudar, pode editá-lo a vontade:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pasta Backup
backup="/home/arcadian/workspace/works/backup"
#Pasta Prod
prod="/home/arcadian/workspace/works/prod"
#Pasta Upload
upload="/home/arcadian/scripts/shell"
#Arquivo txt
txt="/home/arcadian/copiados.txt"

main(){
# Funções, basta comentar pra usar a que deseja.    
deploy
rollback
}

deploy(){

if [ -e $txt ];then
    rm -f $txt;
fi

    for i in $(ls $upload); do
    for a in $(ls $prod); do
        if [[ $a == $i ]];then
            cd $prod
            cp $a $backup
            ls $a >> ~/copiados.txt
            cp -rf $upload/$i $prod
        fi  
    done
done
}

rollback(){
for i in $(cat $txt); do
    rm -rf $prod/$i
    cp -rf $backup/$i $prod
done
}

main
```